# Getline puts program on pause

Tags: c++, buffer, cin, getline

When "text" is larger than about 280 numbers the program waits ...
With any "text" of 280 numbers, it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    getline (cin, text);
    cout << text;
}
```

eg:

```
167 214 280 265 278 292 196 249 242 297 7 125 151 4 25 172 293 157 290 277 240 155 201 90 44 230 94 185 184 65 189 159 74 30 59 279 169 136 142 80 46 124 66 203 138 182 171 241 267 294 32 233 165 39 149 181 156 170 137 96 130 238 239 37 298 48 288 6 100 174 268 144 272 109 275 190 160 154 57 15 83 16 183 236 95 97 147 215 77 34 219 91 68 81 52 207 187 105 229 153 243 20 71 53 3 102 259 13 115 123 98 193 87 208 120 221 113 261 126 178 111 133 255 36 287 93 228 263 47 227 188 191 295 205 28 82 244 152 281 166 58 192 162 60 256 76 50 179 235 247 282 118 88 212 112 21 273 141 222 56 209 134 237 2 121 104 23 150 194 146 24 300 64 92 78 79 116 108 286 223 70 61 67 284 19 33 173 216 42 164 29 199 63 69 140 132 211 101 103 119 106 198 296 168 224 158 232 27 254 246 262 110 250 225 135 86 26 51 180 231 114 257 75 202 217 251 218 18 89 213 85 220 117 266 206 127 234 197 291 248 14 258 129 226 148 260 84 204 73 299 31 264 276 107 11 145 1 54 200 49 72 177 62 45 163 271 274 270 195 186 252 139 99 55 41 38 253 285 5 176 283 22 122 161 17 175 131 43 289 269 9 40 245 12 10 143 35 210 128 8
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input that locks up the program? Your code looks fine. Also, what platform and compiler?

Comment: Did you really count it? And could you show us?

Comment: I use Xcode on a MacBook

Comment: I have added a sample input with 300 numbers that locks up the program after my code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Win10 + VS2015, it should be a platform specific bug / limitation. Probably not even related to C++.

Comment: If you can run this in a debugger, it might be instructive to trace into `getline` and find out exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could imagine your code is pausing is if you were overfilling the space allocated for a string. This seems extremely unlikely. There is a limit to the maximum size for a string based on the size of size_t but typically 32 bits are allocated for size_t... This means that the max number of characters for a string is typically 2^32 - 1 characters. Obviously, you are nowhere near reaching that length.

In normal circumstances, you are far more likely to be bound by the amount of space that your system can allocate for the string. This is dependent on the amount of memory available and how your system breaks it up.

Both of these situations seem extremely unlikely.

In this situation, the issue is most likely an issue with your compiler or platform...

What's your reason for taking in such a long string? Have you considered other approaches like reading in the integers from a text file? You could use a vector to store the integers in a more organized way by reading them in individually from the text file, just a thought.

Comment: Thank you ltnewberry. Have you tried on your compiler with my example with 300 numbers ? I agree with all your remarks but still need to understand my problem.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I did try it myself and I had no issue. I ran it with Code::Blocks on a windows machine

Comment: Hi ltnewberry. Thanks for trying. Are there any specific limitations on Xcode on MacBook ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I've never worked with Xcode. You may consider posting a question with an Xcode tag regarding your problem. Maybe someone else will have more luck understanding the issue